# Display the value of Varargs

Tags: java

In the Java Programming when we pass the all arguments from the varargs then how can i dispaly that argument value.. For example i saw a program something like this :

```
class var{
   static void dis (int...num) {
      System.out.println ("Number of Arguments = " + num.length);
      for (int x : num)
      System.out.println(x + " ");
   }

   public static void main (String args[]) {
      dis();
      dis(1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10);
      dis(12, 14, 16, 18, 20);
   }    
}
```

In the above program what action is performing by `for(int x : num)` .

Comment: Erm... `for (string s : args)
      System.out.println(s + " ");`?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Comment: that is a `for-each` loop.

Comment: "_what action is performing by_" If you ran the code I think it becomes quite obvious what it does.

Answer (score 2):

varargs is just a syntactic sugar on top of getting an array argument - and you can still treat it as such. E.g.:

```
static void dis (int... num) {
  // num is actually an int[]
  System.out.println (Arrays.toString(num));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java the varargs are simply an array.

In the case you've shown: `num` is `int[] num`.

By the same principle you could declare your `main` method as:

```
public static void main(String... args)
```

They're equivalent.

According to the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html):

> the varargs feature automates and hides the process of passing an
>   array to a method.

Answer (score 0):

`for(int x : num)` is an "enhanced for loop". It means that x takes each value in num in turn and the loop is executed with that value. It's just syntactic sugar on an ordinary for loop.